# query with 'NOT IN' condition is too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query that reads about 342 records from one table and checks if the records do not exist in the another table with approximately 32000 records. for this, I have used the 'NOT IN' condition and  What is ever the best way to run a query faster with 'NOT IN' condition as bellow that seems like the process wants to take whole my life!

```
SELECT fname,lname,position 
FROM employees 
WHERE employees.id NOT IN(select projects.empid where projects.id='BRS213F-013')
```

What am I really supposed to do?

Comment: actually this is not the complete query, there is a `FROM` missing in the inner select.

Comment: FoolishSeth, no it is not slow by itself!

Comment: Yes the from is missing but it is obvious the from clause is project that i missed! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about using `LEFT JOIN`,

```
SELECT  a.fname, a.lname, a.position 
FROM    employees a
        LEFT JOIN projects b
            ON  a.ID = b.emp_ID AND
                b.id = 'BRS213F-013'
WHERE   b.emp_ID IS NULL
```

Make sure that `Employees.ID` and `projects.emp_ID` must have keys defined on them to make the performance faster.

---

To make `Employees.ID` a primary key if it has not implemented yet,

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

To make `projects.emp_ID` a foreign key which reference of `Employees.ID` if it has not implemented yet

```
ALTER TABLE Projects 
ADD CONSTRAINT tb_fk FOREIGN KEY (EmpID) REFERENCES Employees (ID)
```

Comment: NOT IN is usually really slow, and this suggestion is the best chance of lowering the time without any structural work on the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fname,lname,position 
FROM employees 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select * where projects.id='BRS213F-013' AND employees.id = projects.empid)
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS is more efficient than not in